# Regression tree splitting (CART, Scikit Learn)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cart

I am working with a Random Forest using scikit-learn and still have some questions and thoughts I am not sure about regarding the splits in regression trees:

1.
It seems to me that scikit-learn's RandomForestRegressor and DecisionTreeRegressor use just one feature at each node in order to split the data set and decide the subsequent node for future samples. Is this true?

2.
The number of features and - in case not all features are considered - the features which are to be considered while looking for the best split at each node, are randomly chosen. That would mean that the overall best split won't occur at some nodes, because the respective feature possibly wasn't even considered. Is this true?

2.2. I read Breiman's CART (1984) but I can't remember the random consideration of features at each node being mentioned there. I could have possibly missed it. Is that something from the original CART algorithm or was this later included in modified algorithms?

3. If (1.) is true: Are there any regression tree algorithms which make splits based on multiple features? (Not considering features for splits, but setting the thresholds for splits based on multiple features)

Comment: To answer (3), there are decision tree algorithms that split along oblique directions in feature space (i.e. by thresholding the projection of the input along this direction). This gives splits that depend on multiple features. But, this is different than determining a separate threshold for each feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. It seems to me that scikit-learn's RandomForestRegressor and DecisionTreeRegressor use just one feature at each node in order to split the data set and decide the subsequent node for future samples. Is this true?

Yes, this is pretty much standard. They would basically evaluate all features to determine the best one regarding node variance (or equiv. MSE) and then pick one.

> 2. The number of features and - in case not all features are considered - the features which are to be considered while looking for the best split at each node, are randomly chosen. That would mean that the overall best split won't occur at some nodes, because the respective feature possibly wasn't even considered. Is this true?

Yes, when I mentioned "all features" above, I was referring to all features "available" for that tree. More specifically regarding "That would mean that the overall best split won't occur at some nodes" -- sure, that's right. If it weren't, there would be no point in a "Random" Forest since all trees would be the same and you would likely overfit terribly.

> 2.2. I read Breiman's CART (1984) but I can't remember the random consideration of features at each node being mentioned there.

CART is a decision tree algorithm. The randomization is per Random Forest algorithm. I.e., the random aspect comes from the fact that the trees don't have access to all features but only a random subset.

> If (1.) is true: Are there any regression tree algorithms which make splits based on multiple features? (Not considering features for splits, but setting the thresholds for splits based on multiple features)

Not sure about this one, but how would you split on multiple features? That's essentially like 2 or more splits then, so you can do it consecutively.

Comment: Thanks! This is helping me a lot already. Regarding 2: When you say "all features 'available' for that tree", you make it sound like the number of features and the features considered for splitting are fixed for each tree in the Random Forest. I am pretty sure, that they vary from node to node inside the trees as well though. In the sklearn docu for the DecisionTreeRegressor it says: "The features are always randomly permuted at each split. Therefore, the best found split may vary, even with the same training data and max_features=n_features"

Comment: I can't tell exactly how this answer was intended, but just to be clear: Each internal node in a tree can only choose from a subset of features. This subset is different for each node, and is selected randomly from the set of *all* features.

Comment: Good points. There are actually 2 approaches for this. (1) One is selecting a random set of features for each tree. (2) The other is providing the tree with the complete subset but then using a random subset at each node. Method (1) is used by Tin Kam Ho in “Random decision forests” (1995) and (2) is proposed by Breiman in “Random forests” (2001). Scikit-learn uses the Random forest by Breiman, i.e., (2)

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the Breiman version, since the OP mentioned using the random forest implementation in scikit-learn. Good to point out the Ho version as well.